# Returning random key and word from array in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with one document. It looks like this:

```
 words: {
   wordOne: ["Cat", "Dog","Fish"],
   wordTwo: ["Red", "Blue", "Green"],
   wordThree: ["Square","Cirecle","Triangle"]
 }
```

I would like to **query the DB to select a random key** (`wordOne`, `wordTwo` or `wordThree`) **and then return a random word from the array on that key**.

So far I've written a query that returns the entire document and then I use JS to select a random key and then a random word. That does work of course but I've read that if you can have the DB do the work, it's better to do it that way. Plus I'm really curious how it would be accomplished.

I'm using Node and mongoose

Comment: If you know the total number of  words (from three words fields) before the query is run (which can be used to generate a random number) - then you can find a random word using an aggregation query. That is with NodeJS driver. But, from a `mongo` shell query you can do it as one aggregation query.

Comment: I can easily get the total number of words. I'll look into that.  Thanks

Comment: Note that this statement is not always true "if you can have the DB do the work, it's better to do it that way" If you are doing something that the database is not optimised to do, it might be better to do it in somewhere else. For example MongoDB does not have a straightforward way to generate a random number. So you could generate the random numbers in node.js and deterministically provide the number to mongodb query as a key / array index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      words: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $objectToArray: "$words"
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $map: {
                  input: "$$this.v",
                  as: "w",
                  in: {
                    key: "$$this.k",
                    word: "$$w"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$words"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$words" // For MongoDB v3.4 $replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$words"}
  },
  {
    $sample: {
      size: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jy-hYFKVyHw)

Answer (score 1):

You can transform all the arrays contatined within `words` object by using [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html), [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) and [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html). This will give you one long array of all strings which can be then passed as a parameter to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get single word per document. Lastly you can run [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) to get random document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            all: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$words" },
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this.v" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$all"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            sampleWord: "$all"
        }
    },
    {
        $sample: { size: 1 }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RxCl1qvu2Z-)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. To further this thoughIs there a way that I could have it return the random word and the key? For example if Dog were the returned word have it return `{ sampleWord: Dog, key: wordOne }`

Comment: @pdad04 sure, same pattern, just `$$this.k` instead of `$$this.v` and both can be run at once using `$facet`: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ofYFAztHDLc